# Unable to use ttyUSB0 as console

Tags: boot, command-line, usb, kernel, serial-port

I have a server (Ubuntu 20.04.1 Kernel 5.4.0-42-generic) that is meant to be headless and able to be remote rebooted (with encrypted root) I have a USB to Serial adapter in the machine and was wanting to use this as a console at boot time to enable headless/remote unlocking of the encrypted root.

I am able to successfully connect to the console once host is booted after enabling *serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service* so the adapter works and is cabled correctly.

I have added "**console=tty0 console=ttyUSB0**" to GRUB at boot time but this appears to be outright ignored by the kernel.

```
$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=/dev/mapper/host--vg-host_root--lv ro ipv6.disable=1 console=tty0 console=ttyUSB0
[    0.056872] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=/dev/mapper/host--vg-host_root--lv ro ipv6.disable=1 console=tty0 console=ttyUSB0
[    0.115389] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.458997] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[   54.731750] usb 1-1.5: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I have tested using "**console=tty0 console=ttyS0**" which appears to work though I have no serial port connected to that interface so unable to verify and would prefer to have this working via USB rather than needing to source a port header

```
$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=/dev/mapper/host--vg-host_root--lv ro ipv6.disable=1 console=ttyS0 console=tty0
[    0.056348] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=/dev/mapper/host--vg-host_root--lv ro ipv6.disable=1 console=ttyS0 console=tty0
[    0.115326] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[   26.469014] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[   40.385803] 00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[   51.949414] tty tty40: hash matches
[   87.762789] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[   91.428703] usb 1-1.5: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

My current theory is that the kernel has not been compiled with CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_CONSOLE enabled.

So my questions...

1. Is my theory correct and I am unable to do this with current kernel build?
   1a) If so is there any way to request this be added in future kernel builds?
2. Is there something I am missing that would get this to work?

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. Also the getty works when starting this 'manually' by systemctl.

```
marc@thirdworld:/var/log$ dmesg | grep -Ei 'console|ttyUSB'
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-135-generic root=UUID=0787120b-7858-4ca3-a7aa-b04533fc707e ro ipv6.disable=1 console=tty0 console=ttyUSB0,115200n8 splash quiet ipv6.disable=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.030445] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-135-generic root=UUID=0787120b-7858-4ca3-a7aa-b04533fc707e ro ipv6.disable=1 console=tty0 console=ttyUSB0,115200n8 splash quiet ipv6.disable=1 vt.handoff=7
[    0.076533] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.076537] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    1.582709] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    2.526967] usb 3-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    4.010005] usb 3-1.4.3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[    4.838555] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
```

Looks like the device module ('... attached to ttyUSB0...) is loaded after the console is enabled.

I have already added the modules for the usb to serial converter to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules and updated the initramfs.

I hope someone will have an answer...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1271458)